# How to find everything that is not matching a regular expression

Tags: css, regex, regex-negation

I would like to search all over thousands of HTML code for bad practice of height, width or any other CSS.

for instance I would like to get all places where height is not provided with units, for instance `height:40` should be found, but `height:40px` shouldn't.

For that I am using the search program agent ransack, in which I can put regular expression to search within files.

Currently my regular expression is:

```
(height:)[\s]*[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(px)
```

this finds everything that is like `height:40px`. (Later on I want to add width, or other things)

My question is how to make a NOT on top of all that?

Or is there any other good application to search files for regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead `(?!regex)`, eg:

```
height:\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?!px|\d)
```

`\d` is needed to prevent backtracking alternatives from matching.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but this doesnt seem to work well. I've check in the search program (agentRansack) and also with online regex: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/     this still seems to return unwanted results.

Comment: not working for instance height:440px - it still finds and returns height:44 in this string

Comment: @Tal, because `\d+` backtracks. `(?!px)` checks that the following is not `px`, which it isn't, it's `0px`. See update.

Comment: great thanks ,but double checking, this still doesnt catch the height:4.5px for example. is the final correct one the following: height:\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?!px|\d|\.\d)

Answer (score 0):

Use the negative lookahead this way:

```
(?!height:\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?px)height:\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

Considering you are using css, you may want to include other units as valid ones like `pt`, `em`, `%`, etc... like the below regex

```
(?!height:\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:px|pt|em|%|cm|mm|in|ex|pc))height:\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

You can test it over [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/HhxmcY8MD1)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a program that already does this, and add you own rules.  In general, the practice of fixing up source code is called 'linting'.  So, you can find quickly something like CSSLint which is open source and allows custom rules:

https://github.com/stubbornella/csslint/wiki/Rules

http://csslint.net/